# Sending email subject in Python

Tags: python, email, python-3.x, smtp, smtplib

I am having issues getting the Subject portion of my emails to show up when my program sends email. I thought I was following the RFC spec for SMTP.. but i cant seem to figure out what I am doing wrong. Any help is greatly appreciated.

```
def email():

    sender = 'username@domain.com'
    receivers = ['username@domain.com']

    message = """From: From Admin <admin@domain.com>
    To:To Person <user@domain.com>
    Subject: Important Information

    This is a test email message.
    """ 
    try:
        smtpObj = smtplib.SMTP('domain.com', 25)
        smtpObj.sendmail(sender, receivers, message)
        print "Successfully sent email"
    except smtplib.SMTPException:
        print('Error: unable to send email')
```

Comment: What error or unexpected result do you get?

Comment: (no subject) in the subject of the email.. i don't understand why even though I am giving it a subject in the email i'm creating

Comment: Your headers need to be seperated with \r\n.

Comment: @jordanm - that shouldn't be the problem [`smtplib` takes care of that](http://hg.python.org/cpython/file/c4d884d5d86c/Lib/smtplib.py#l159). To avoid errors when creating email messages it woule be better to use the [`email`](docs.python.org/library/email) module.

Comment: How does the headers in the received message look? Is the subject line there, has it dissappeared, is it mangled in some way?

Answer (score 1):

Not sure what the problem is with your code.

FWIW, I've used string.join to create my message body in the past:

```
def send_email():
    import string,smtplib

    SMTPserver = "smtp.com"
    # To is a comma-separated list
    To = "sender@domain.com"
    From = "receipient@domain.com"
    Subj = "test subject"
    Text = """test email.
    Not sure what the problem is
    Multi-line anyway."""

    Body = string.join((
        "From: %s" % From,
        "To: %s" % To,
        "Subject: %s" % Subj,
        "",
        Text,
        ), "\r\n")

    s = smtplib.SMTP(SMTPserver)
    s.sendmail(From,[To],Body)

    s.quit()
```

-J

Answer (score 0):

Try the example from http://docs.python.org/library/email-examples.html
Or give my example code a go. I didnt need the from header but I guess you can add it if you want.

```
import smtplib

USER_NAME = 'username@domain.com'
PASSWORD = getpass.getpass("%s's PASSWORD: " % USER_NAME)
DEBUG = True
MESSAGE_FORMAT = "From: %s\r\nTo: %s\r\nSubject: %s\r\n\r\n%s" # %(fromAddr,to,subject,text)

def sendEmail(recipient,message):
    SMTP_SERVER_URL = 'smtp.gmail.com'
    mailserver = smtplib.SMTP(SMTP_SERVER_URL)
    if DEBUG: 
        mailserver.set_debuglevel(1)
        mailserver.ehlo()
        mailserver.starttls()
        mailserver.ehlo()
    mailserver.login(USER_NAME,PASSWORD)
    mailserver.sendmail('', recipient, message)
    mailserver.close()

def sendEmailWithFields(to,subject,text):
    message = MESSAGE_FORMAT%('', to, subject, text)
    sendEmail(to,message)

if __name__ == '__main__':
    to = 'receipient@domain.com'
    subject = 'The subject'
    text = 'The text body'
    sendEmailWithFields(to,subject,text)
```